# Gulp restart the server when i changed my front end(Angularjs) controller file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gulp

I have this gulpfile.js

```
// Dependencies
var gulp = require('gulp');
var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');
// var notify = require('gulp-notify');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');

// Task
gulp.task('default', function () {
   // listen for changes
   livereload.listen();
   // configure nodemon
   nodemon({
      // the script to run the app
      script: 'server.js',
      ext: 'js'
   }).on('restart', function () {
      // when the app has restarted, run livereload.
      gulp.src('server.js')
         .pipe(livereload())
      //    .pipe(notify('Reloading page, please wait...'));
   })
})
```

I want to reload gulp only if my server.js (server-side) file changed,

but if i changed front end file in angularjs **controller.js**, gulp restarting the server.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I use the nodemon option watch

```
nodemon({
   // the script to run the app
   script: 'server.js',
   // comment or remove this line ext: 'js',
   ignore: ['js/controller.js'], // you can also specify directories/files to ignore
   // add watch array here
   watch: [
     //directories that you want to watch ex: src/**/*.js
     'server.js' // you can be as specific as you want try this.
   ]
}).on('restart', function () {
   // when the app has restarted, run livereload.
   gulp.src('server.js')
      .pipe(livereload())
//    .pipe(notify('Reloading page, please wait...'));
})
```

Comment: it stills restarting the server, when i make changes in client side file.

Comment: I think it's likely the livereload, I believe it is watching all files. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: still reloading the client side :'(

Comment: the nodemon ext option watches all files in the project with the specified extention

Comment: how to exclude? my js/controller.js file?

Comment: all of the options I provided have worked for my project